# php irc bot with periodic messages to the channel

Tags: php, bots, irc

I follow some tutorial to create the bot from scratch, and the basic functionality working fine, like I can connect, it responds to commands, and outputs the to the webpage.

What I want is periodicity send messages with updates to channel that I'm getting from some website with curl.

$irc and $curl are just arrays with settings, and date('s') is lets say the function that returns the updates. Of course I have working curl function for that. The $irc['delay'] is set to 10, so with sleep(1) it should send update every 10 sec.

The problem is that like for the first minute or so it send current seconds every 10 sec, but it doesn't listen to any of the commands that I set. It does the commands after that first initial delay, that I'm not where it's coming from
Then it message the current seconds (the if condition) only if someone talks on the channel. I guess it waits for these 128 bytes? But it does listen to commands instantly.

```
while(1) {
    while($data = fgets($socket, 128)) {
        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        if ($curl['delay'] <= $d) { fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$irc['channel']." :".date('s')."\n"); $d=0; };
        $d+=1;
        sleep(1);

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);
        if($ex[0] == "PING") fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        $command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $ex[3]);
        switch ($command) {
            case ":!say" : fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$ex[2]." :Hello!\n"); break;
            case ":!off" : break 3;
        };
    };
}
```

Well I want it both respond to the commands, and automatically message pulled data periodically. But I don't understand it's behavior, nor even sure what I want is possible with php anymore

Like Ranty suggested
without break:
It will say the date once, and then it will take at least minute for next report. If I say any command it further delays it.

10:39 Moninal  I came 
10:39 Moninal 39:24 
10:40 Moninal 40:26

10:41 Moninal  I came 
10:41 Moninal 41:05 
10:41 Gregos !sayit 
10:41 Moninal Hello! 
10:41 Gregos !sayit 
10:41 Moninal Hello! 
10:42 Moninal 42:51

After it sent the second message I get output on the webpage for first time, and every next report is sent every 61 seconds, not 10 seconds.

10:42 Moninal 42:51
10:43 Moninal 43:52
10:44 Moninal 44:53

If I add break in the inner loop:
For first minute I get reports every 10 seconds, but all sent commands triggered at the end of that first minute, like before.
After that time commands works, but again reports every 61 seconds.

Maybe it's something with my server config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after day of suffering i finally found the silly reason and solution. Basically the reason for the 1 min delay is the fget command while($data = fgets($socket, 128));

The workaround is to set stream_set_timeout($socket,1); before the loop. Well I also ended up setting up nginx server instead of apache. I'm not sure if that helps anyhow though. 
Also I think I can just set the time in the stream_set_timeout($socket,1); to control the minimum interval of sending messages.

```
$next=time();
stream_set_timeout($socket,1);
while(1) {

    $data = fgets($socket, 128);
    echo nl2br($data);

    $ex = explode(' ', $data);
    if($ex[0] == "PING") fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
    if (isset($ex[3])) $command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $ex[3]);

    switch ($command) {
        case ":!sayit" : 
            $msg = NULL; for ($i = 4; $i < count($ex); $i++) { $msg .= $ex[$i] . ' '; }
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$ex[2]." :".$msg."\n"); 
            break;
        case ":!off" :
          fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$irc['channel']." : Bye\n");
          fputs($socket,"QUIT Client Disconnected!\n");
          die('Exited!');
    };

    if ($next <= time()) {
        fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$irc['channel']." :".date('H:i:s')."\n");
        echo "PRIVMSG ".$irc['channel']." :".date('H:i:s')."<br />";
        $next = time() + $curl['delay']; 
    };
    flush(); 
};
```

Well and it doesn't include all the connection setup. That can be easily found how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you have all logic within `while($data = fgets($socket, 128))` loop. If you think about it, your logic is executed *if there is something in chat happening*. So when you start the script, it executes ok, since it reads the data that was there (I assume so), but after that data is read, it only executes on new data.

Now it only prints seconds on chat, because it waits 10 times of 128 bytes (what you meant to be 10 seconds), because it will be 10 seconds only if the inner while loop condition is always true (if it's executed every second).

You could try to move some of the logic outside of the inner while loop. I also changed curl timing for you - the way you make it sleep for 1 second and add 1 to the counter - that is not reliable. You can simply compare current time to time of last request.

```
while(1) {
    flush();

    if ($curl['next_request'] <= time()) {
        fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$irc['channel']." :".date('s')."\n");
        $curl['next_request'] = time() + $curl['delay'];
    };

    while($data = fgets($socket, 128)) {
        echo nl2br($data);
        $ex = explode(' ', $data);
        if($ex[0] == "PING") fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        $command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $ex[3]);
        switch ($command) {
            case ":!say" : fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$ex[2]." :Hello!\n"); break;
            case ":!off" : break 3;
        };
    };

    sleep(1);
}
```

It will likely respond to all commands simultaneously, not 1 per second, if you want to change that, you can try adding a break at the end of the inner while.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but no, I'll edit my main post to say what happens? Since there's limit.

Comment: Debug curl block separately. It is now separate, so that's possible. Echo variables to see what's wrong. It's wired that it doesn't echo seconds every now and then.